# conjugacy to elliptic Möbius transformation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, mobius-transformation

I got stuck on the following statement:

Let $g$ be an element of $\mathrm{Homeo}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ such that $g^m = e$ for some integer $m>1$. Pick any point $x \in \mathbb{S}^1$. Then $A_x = \{g^k(x): k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is finite, and $g$ permutes the components of $\mathbb{S}^1 \backslash A_x$. Therefore, $g$ is conjugate to an elliptic Mobius transformation.

$\textbf{My question is}$: Why do these conditions imply that $g$ is conjugate to an elliptic Möbius transform?

Any hints are welcome! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: First try to guess which elliptic transform $f$ your $g$ is conjugate to. Then construct a subset $B_x$ for $f$ similar to the one for $g$. Now, construct conjugating homeomorphism on one of the complementary intervals of $B_x$ sending it to one of $A_x$...

Comment: @studiosus Is $f$should be just usual rotation of the circle of order $m$?

Comment: Yes. Now, think about the rest of the steps.

Comment: @studiosus thank you! I got the steps you proposed before.